# How can I predict Naive Bayes data(spam or ham)?

Tags: naive-bayes

For example, I have Naive Bayes data like

data : probability

Fastest : 1

digit : 0

Find    : 0.643234

Forum   : 0.562904

Free    : 0.857344

I might say if there is a word "data" in a certain document, I might predict that document is spam and word "digit" is ham. However, what should I have to do with other words?